# java trouble with class instance variable and constructor

Tags: java, arraylist, parameters, constructor, instance

I have been racking my brain over this and trying to do research, but what I have found hasn't helped me crack it yet. I am at this point really hoping someone can help me point in a clear direction, or show me exactly what I am doing wrong and misunderstanding. I seem to be having trouble understanding and dealing with constructors, and parameters for a new instance of a class. Please note that I am just learning so I apologize if I may have used the wrong terms.

```
public class CommissionCalculation 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // create scanner for user input from command window
        Employee employee = new Employee(employee.name, employee.totalSales, employee.totalIncome); //create instance of employee class
```

The specific error I am getting is the instance parameter employee.name, which says "Variable employee might not have been initialized." However, employee.totalSales, and employee.totalIncome do not have this problem.

I am trying to pass these parameters into an `ArrayList` as you can see below.

```
  ArrayList <Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();//create arraylist of employee class        
  employeeList.add(new Employee(employee.name, employee.totalSales, employee.totalIncome));
```

class code is

```
class Employee //creates new class 
{
    String name;
    double totalSales;
    double totalIncome;

    public Employee(String Name, double TotalSales, double TotalIncome)
    {
        this.name = Name;
        this.totalSales = TotalSales;
        this.totalIncome = TotalIncome;
    }

    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getTotalSales() 
    {
        return totalSales;
    }
    public void setTotalSales(double totalSales) 
    {
    this.totalSales = totalSales;
    }

    public double getTotalIncome()
    {
        return totalIncome;
    }
    public void setTotalIncome(double totalIncome)
    {
        this.totalIncome = totalIncome;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Name: "+ this.name + "\nTotal Annual Sales: "+ this.totalSales + "\nTotal Income Earned:" + this.totalIncome;
    }
}
```

All help and suggestions are very much appreciated!

Comment: I think you'll find employee.totalSales,and employee.totalIncome have the same problem: try replacing employee.name with "Fred" and you'll see the syntax error moves to the next argument.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `Employee employee = new Employee(employee.name, employee.totalSales, employee.totalIncome)`, `employee.name` is the name of the Employee you are currently constructing.

You basically say "The name of this employee should be the name of this employee", and then Java asks "But what *is* the name of this employee?"

If you call a constructor like that, you have to call it with a concrete value (or a variable that already has a value), so for example `Employee employee = new Employee("John Doe", "245", "1234.56")`

If you just want to create an empty employee, you'll have to have a constructor like this:

```
public Employee() {
}
```

This will allow you to set the values later. You can also add default values to the variables inside it if you want to.
You can call the constructor like this:

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
```

By the way, if you don't define any constructors at all, this one will be added by default. (In that case, it's called the "default constructor".)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find employee.totalSales,and employee.totalIncome have the same problem: try replacing employee.name with "Fred" and you'll see the syntax error moves to the next argument. The problem is that the value you are passing to the constructor need to have a value before the constructor is called. The employee variable hasn't been initialised yet so they don't have a value - which is what the compiler is telling you in the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting is the instance parameter employee.name, which says
>   "Variable employee might not have been initialized." However,
>   employee.totalSales, and employee.totalIncome do not have this
>   problem.

If you provide valid parameters, you will get compile time error for other two parameters as well.

```
Demo.java:3: error: variable employee might not have been initialized
    Employee employee = new Employee(null, employee.totalSales, employee.totalIncome);
                                           ^
Demo.java:3: error: variable employee might not have been initialized
    Employee employee = new Employee(null, 0, employee.totalIncome);
                                              ^
```

As suggested by @Jake, have a default constructor and initialize employee fields.